Why value_counts and nunique are slowing down a spreadsheet check?
I'm reading ~4000 excel files with one sheet and each sheet has around 200 rows and 10 columns.
To validate the dataframes I made for each file, I'm making nine simple checks of the content and the format of the spreadsheet. The whole process takes ~6 minutes, which is relatively fine.
Now, I added another check check_10 and suddenly the process takes now ~20 minutes.
This check is targeting four columns of the spreadsheet that looks like below dataframe :
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['381', '381', '381', '381', '381', '381', '381', '381', '381', '381', '382', '382', '382', '382', '382', '382', '382', '382', '382', '382'], 'components': ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1'], 'capacity': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'], 'chunks': ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6']})

def check_10(df):
    cols = ['id', 'capacity', 'chunks']

    counts = df.groupby(cols, as_index=False)['components'].agg(total_components='value_counts')
    counts['unique_components'] = counts.groupby(cols)['components'].transform('nunique')

    result1 = counts['unique_components'].le(counts['capacity'].astype(int)).all()
    result2 = counts['total_components'].eq(vc['chunks'].astype(int)).all()

    return result1 and result2

print(check_10(df))
# False

The purpose of check_10 is to make sure that for each id (that has a fixed capacity and number of chunks), the number of unique components don't exceed the capacity of the id and the total of components is equal to the number of chunks of the given id.
For information, counts looks like this :
print(counts)
#     id  capacity  chunks components  total_components  unique_components
# 0  381         1       4         A1                 6                  2
# 1  381         1       4         B1                 4                  2
# 2  382         2       6         A1                 6                  2
# 3  382         2       6         C1                 4                  2

Do you guys know why the check I added is slowing down my code ?

Are you calling this N=4000 times, one for each dataframe? Maybe your variable assignments are exhausting memory. Try parameterizing N and use a lower value, and watch memory usage as you increase N and see if that explains the slowdown.

Also, df.groupby does an unwanted sort on columns, turn that off for speed

Yes my friend, I run the ten checks for each file separately, that is a total of 4000x10 checks. I will try to deactivate sort in groupby and let you know. I have a feeling that check_10  is the main problem because 4000x9 checks takes 6 minutes.

My first suggestion was only run for N=10 instead of 4000 dataframes and check the runtime is linear and how much is memory usage. Then keep doubling N until you break it

@VERBOSE - How solution working?

It worked very good. Thank you so much my friend.

EDIT1 Solution with one groupby:
def f(x):
    i, cap, chunks = x.name

    result2 = (x.value_counts() == int(chunks)).all()
    result1 = len(set(x)) <= int(cap)
        
    return result1 and result2

cols = ['id', 'capacity', 'chunks']
out = df.groupby(cols, sort=False)['components'].apply(f).any()

Optimalization with Counter:
from collections import Counter

def f(x):
    i, cap, chunks = x.name
    
    counts = Counter(x).values()
    result2 = all([x == int(chunks) for x in counts])
    result1 = len(counts) <= int(cap)
    # print (result1)
    return result1 and result2

cols = ['id', 'capacity', 'chunks']
out = df.groupby(cols)['components'].apply(f).any()

Alternative:
from collections import Counter

def f(i, cap, chunks, x):
    
    counts = Counter(x).values()
    result2 = all([x == int(chunks) for x in counts])
    result1 = len(counts) <= int(cap)
    # print (result1)
    return result1 and result2

cols = ['id', 'capacity', 'chunks']
out = any([f(i,cap,chunks,x) for (i,cap,chunks),x in df.groupby(cols)['components']])


EDIT: You can test conditions in 2 different DataFrames:
def check_10(df):
    cols = ['id', 'capacity', 'chunks']
   
    counts = (df.groupby(cols + ['components']).size()
                .reset_index(name='total_components'))
    print (counts)
        id capacity chunks components  total_components
    0  381        1      4         A1                 6
    1  381        1      4         B1                 4
    2  382        2      6         A1                 6
    3  382        2      6         C1                 4
    
    counts1 = counts.groupby(cols).size().reset_index(name='unique_components')
    print (counts1)
        id capacity chunks  unique_components
    0  381        1      4                  2
    1  382        2      6                  2
        
    result1 = counts1['unique_components'].le(counts1['capacity'].astype(int)).all()
    result2 = counts['total_components'].eq(counts['chunks'].astype(int)).all()

    return result1 and result2

print(check_10(df))

I think there are unique values in components column in counts DataFrame, so is possible simplify code from:
counts['unique_components'] = counts.groupby(cols)['components'].transform('nunique')

to:
counts['unique_components'] = counts.groupby(cols)['components'].transform('size')

Another idea is create one big DataFrame with 4000 x 200 rows and working with this DataFrame - instead 4k small one.

Thank you my friend. I will test your first solution and let you know how much time it takes. But I feel like the improvement won't be big because we still using two .groupby. Can you show me please to do one signle groupby instead of two ? And for your second solution, I can't do that because some files have missing columns, that's why I run the ten checks for each spreadsheet separately.

@VERBOSE - Understand - I try add another optimilized solution with one groupby, I hope working well for you
